# Returning an index of an alphabetical list python

Tags: list, python-3.x

So I'm working on a homework for a beginning python class.  I'm asked to write a function taking two parameters, one a string and one of a list in alphabetical order.  The function is to return the integer index as to where the string would be placed in order for the list to stay alphabetized.

I am not allowed to insert anything into the list, or append the list in any matter (I tried just adding the string to the list, resorting and then returning the index for where the string now lived)  All the function is to return is the integer index value.  I could use some direction as to where to start without using an insert and resorting... Thanks.

Comment: My thought process is to run a loop, comparing my string to each individual string in the list.  But I'm not sure how to make the comparison... I feel like I could do this with integers, but not entirely sure where to go with strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because I dont want to write your homework for you, here is one way to do it in pseudo-code:

```
def insert_index(string, list)
    for every item in your list:
        if the item is greater than your string:
             return index of item
        else:
             go to next item
```

weirdly enough, because of the way python is written, this is very close to actual code...

because strings are comparable, you can actually do something like `'a'<'b'` and return a valid bool. and since your list is alphabetical, as soon as you hit an item that is greater than your string, then you know thats where you want your string to go.

also, it would be useful to use `enumerate` function for your loop structure (HINT HINT)

Comment: I had no clue I could run comparisons on strings.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I would iterate over the list and compare the current string in the list with the string you are trying to insert ( `< >` comparators work on strings, with `'b' > 'a'`. Without giving too much away, take advantage of the fact that the list you are given is already in alphabetical order to determine which index the passed in string would be placed in.

Comment: So python will make comparisons with strings?  I feel like I could do this with integers as 1<2... python understands that 'a' < 'b'? This may get me where I'm going...

Answer (score -1):

One cool thing in python is that letters are of a higher value if they are farther along in the alphabet. For example, 'b' > 'a'. In fact, you can type 'b' > 'a' into an interpreter and it will tell you 'true'. So simply loop through the alphabetical list comparing the first letter in the list item to the first letter in the string.
Something like this (I haven't checked it, so it may not work perfectly, but try to get the gist of it)

```
for i in range(0,len(list)):
    if (list[i][0] < str[0]):
        print(i)
        break
```

Comment: First character ordering isn't python specific ; that's more a property of ASCII, then OP said it's a list in alphabetical order ; not a list which contains the alphabet ; finally there is IMO little point in giving a direct answer to some homework problem.